# How to simplify circuit with multiple batteries?

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

I'm interested in the circuit where we have multiple batteries and all of them have different emf (electromotive force) and resistance. For example, can I simplify this circuit so that I have only one battery with specific emf and resistance or how can I calculate the value of emf and resistance of this circuit:

[image]

Comment: I don't have time for an answer at the moment, but the short answer is to start by breaking the real battery into an ideal voltage source and a series resistor.  Then you can use any took (like KVL) to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you have a circuit with multiple batteries consider using the [method of superposition](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/superposition-theorem/). The article I have linked calls this technique:

> one of those strokes of genius that takes a complex subject and simplifies it in a way that makes perfect sense

and I fully agree with this sentiment. It can be a little tedious when you have lots of batteries but it is simple and always works. The technique is absurdly simple. You take the circuit and replace each battery but one with a wire, or with a resistor equal to their internal resistance if they have an internal resistance, then calculate the currents due to the single battery. Repeat this for every battery in the circuit, then just sum up all the calculated currents.

The method works because simple components like resistors are linear i.e. the current is proportional to the applied voltage. The potential at any point is just the sum of the potentials due to all the batteries individually, so the current is just the sum of all the currents due to the batteries individually.